# Multiple frameworks on one URL with Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, frameworks, flask

Note: URLs, usernames, etc. have been changed for privacy.

I am designing an API in Flask, but the website is originally in PHP. Eventually this will be changed, but for the moment I would like both to run side by side on the same url, we will call it domain.com. The Flask API should be located at www.domain.com/api and the PHP website at www.domain.com.

The Apache file for the websites is located at: /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com. By using one of the individual settings below and restarting apache, I can get that framework to run alone, but I have not figured out how to get them both in the file and running without issues.

Flask (www.domain.com/api):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName www.domain.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess api user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/user/public_html/api/api.wsgi

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/api>
        WSGIProcessGroup api
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PHP (www.domain.com):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName  www.domain.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/domain.com/


</VirtualHost>
```

I have experimented with a number of things like Directory and Alias, but I have not been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: What does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: if you run the second virtualhost with the php website working, what is your issue with flask? did you tried to put flask in /home/user/public_html/domain.com/api ?

Comment: If I have both of those in the file then only the virtual host that is written first gets used.

Comment: Hmm, only solution I can think of now is to just use another port number for the API since it will not be accessed by a web browser anyway, but I will still hold out a bit for an answer.

Comment: that's not what i said. I asked you if you just use the second, what is the issue with flask?

Comment: It pulls up a folder with the contents of api. Apache needs WSGIScriptAlias and the other items in the first one to run Flask.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple when I discovered that WSGIScriptAlias works similarly to Alias. Then I can simply combine the two and it works how I want it to.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName  www.domain.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/domain.com/

  WSGIDaemonProcess api user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/user/public_html/api/api.wsgi

  <Directory /home/user/public_html/api>
    WSGIProcessGroup api
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```